# JavaScript -- Unable to pass object to onclick method

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image and when its clicked I am trying to pass an object to the onclick method but I get an error:

```
missing ) after argument list
```

the debugger console is showing the error on line 1, the same line as the HTML doctype declaration.

BUT, when I pass a string, everything works fine and the method is executed.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

```
var item = {test:"blah"};// throws error
var emptyString= "";//works fine                                
str = str + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" data-qtip="Submit Report" height="14px" width="14px" src="'+img+'" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="submitReport('+item+')"/>';
```

If I pass in emptyString, everything works fine.

thanks!

Comment: You can create the element and add properties and events _in JavaScript_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stringify object using `JSON.stringify` function:

```
str = str + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" data-qtip="Submit Report" height="14px" width="14px" src="'+img+'" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="submitReport('+JSON.stringify(item)+')"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two things. You try to put an object into a string, that is not possible. You have to stringify the object (e.g. make it a string), to pass it like this.

```
str = str + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" data-qtip="Submit Report" height="14px" width="14px" src="'+img+'" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="submitReport('+JSON.stringify(item)+')"/>';
```

To get the string back to an object in `submitReport()`, you need to parse it:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(stringifiedObject);
```